# How to wait till the view in the container view is loaded?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, properties, viewdidload

I've got such situation :

I have a `UIViewController` ***VC1*** which has a container view. This container view holds another `UIViewController` – ***VC2***. I need to set a property in ***VC2*** and after it was set update the texts on some labels that are connected to VC2 as `IBOutlet`s. I can access VC2 by performing a segue which I created in storyboard with identifier "segueToVC2". I call a `performSegueWithIdentifier` method after the property of VC1 – PROPERTY1 was set, i.e. I call a `performSegueWithIdentifier` in the PROPERTY1's `didSet` method. The thing is that the view of the VC2 which is held by container view is not yet loaded and IBOutlets that I've connected to VC2 are all nil. This causes my app to crash.

How do I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you set up the container view in the storyboard you can simply setup your VC2 in `prepareForSegue` without manually calling `performSegue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've managed to solve the issue in the same way that I've been dealing with `VC1`:
I've set the needed property of `VC2` directly from `AppDelegate` and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what IBOutlets are, haven't programmed Objective-C yet.
Also, I'm not sure why you need to use `performSegueWithIdentifier`, since you tell us VC2 is contained in a container view.

The container view in VC1 links to VC2 using an embedded segue.
You would get a copy of VC2 in `prepareForSegue` and in your `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` you can set the property of VC2.

That's how I do it on Xamarin.iOS anyway.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the properties (text, color, etc.) of the IBOutlets in VC2 in `viewDidLoad` method. Now to set those values from VC1 you should create some properties on VC2 to hold the data you want to pass from VC1 to VC2. Then on 'prepareForSegue' method in VC1 set the properties you want on VC2. And then in VC2 `viewDidLoad` use those properties to update your IBOutlets.